# Server Variables are not being accessible in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have two web applications hosted in the same app pool in IIS 7. One is an ASP.NET application and the other is ASP.NET MVC application. When I go to the web application in ASP.NET and click on a link it is supposed to Launch the other web application in MVC hosted in the same app pool. I can access Server Variables in the ASP.NET application, but I can't access Server Variables in ASP.NET MVC. This works in IIS 6.0 but doesn't work in IIS 7.0. Any ideas and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Can you show where you access the server variables (action, filter, eventhandler in global.asax) and how you do it?

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to see the other's app data (be it server variables or whatever). This is normal. Just because they're in the same process this does not provide access to them.